# How to generate PDF from HTML with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I want to generate PDF from HTML. The libraries I tried are `print.js`, `jsPDF`

With `print.js` I have HTML and trying to make it to PDF and it succeed, but the PDF is only the HTML, without the CSS. But that does not suit me. [Sample example](https://jsfiddle.net/stanimirsp5/2mqpaf7L/4/)

```html
<table id="printJS-form">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<button type="button" onclick="printJS('printJS-form', 'html')">
    Print Form
</button>

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

The closest thing to success was with `jsPDF`, where I create image this time with all css and then generate from that image PDF. But the problem here is that generated PDF is just image and I lose all meta data from the PDF. [Sample example](http://jsfiddle.net/stanimirsp5/u8z1p74f/8/)

```html
<body>
  <div id="printJS-form">

   <h3 id='head-color'>Test heading</h3>
   <button id='print-btn'>Start print process</button>
  </div>
</body>

$('#print-btn').click(()=>{
   var pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.addHTML(document.body,function() {
    pdf.save('web.pdf');
 });
})

#head-color{
  color: blue;
}
```

Another thing I tried and really hope to make it here, because it seems cleaner option for me, is with *"onbeforeprint"* event. Here right before `window.print()` to be called, *"onbeforeprint"* event is activated. And **if** in *"onbeforeprint"*, PDF is already generated I want somehow to access it. But I can`t figure out how and whether it is at all possible. [Sample example](https://jsfiddle.net/stanimirsp5/p1cL3vrb/3/)

```html
<html>
<body onbeforeprint="myFunction()">

<h1>Try to print this document</h1>
<p><b>Tip:</b> Keyboard shortcuts, such as Ctrl+P sets the page to print.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> The onbeforeprint event is not supported in Safari and Opera.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="printWindow()">
    Print Form
</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
// get blob pdf
  alert("You are about to print this document!");
}
function printWindow() {
 window.print();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And finally I'm asking

**Is there a way, with print.js or jsPDF, to get not just the html, but the css too?**

**Can I get binary PDF from *"onbeforeprint"* event or any other javascript event?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could use [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to generate a pdf. I've not tried it but here are some links that demonstrate this approach:

- [advanced-pdf-generation-for-node-js-using-puppeteer](https://medium.com/@raphaelstaebler/advanced-pdf-generation-for-node-js-using-puppeteer-e168253e159c)
- [pdf-from-html-node-js-puppeteer](https://blog.risingstack.com/pdf-from-html-node-js-puppeteer/)
- [high-quality-pdf-generation-using-puppeteer](https://codeburst.io/high-quality-pdf-generation-using-puppeteer-5b51e2ab231a)